# Attach click event for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day, I want to attach click method to div, by BIND method.
My code of attaching is

```
$("#brend_list > #mCSB_1 > .mCSB_container > div > a").bind('click',function(){
id=$(this).attr('id');
ttl=$(this).parent().children("span").html();
state=$(this).hasClass("checked");

if(state) {$(this).removeClass("checked");
$("#"+id+"_filter").remove();
}
else{$(this).addClass("checked");


$("#filters").append(" <div style='display:inline-block;' id='"+id+"_filter' class='filter_brands' onclick='brend_uncheck(\""+id+"\"); $(this).remove();'><span>"+ttl+"</span><b>x</b></div> ");


}});
```

My div structure is

```
<div id="brend_list" class="mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1">
  <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light" id="mCSB_1" style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;">
   <div class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div><a id="filt_brend001"></a><span>Loreal Paris</span></div><!-- this <a> -->
    <div><a id="filt_brend002"></a><span>Laura Mercier</span></div>
    ...........
    </div>
    <div class="mCSB_scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: block;">
      <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer"><div class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; height: 110px; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="position: relative; line-height: 110px;">  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mCSB_draggerRail">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't attach.

Comment: Is your code in a $(document).ready event?

Comment: You're binding the handler to the `A` inside the `DIV`. But there's no text in the `A`, so there's nothing to click on.

Comment: there is an image on BG of a, so there is something on click. Before some changes, it worked, but then I add some divs for scrolling, and it crashed

Comment: You want to attach a click event to div with class `filter_brands`?

Answer (score 2):

You should either change

```
$("#brend_list > #mCSB_1 > .mCSB_container > div > a")
```

to

```
$("#brend_list > #mCSB_1 > .mCSB_container > div > a + span")
```

A fiddle with above is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2N7jk/).

or, change the HTML from

```
<div><a id="filt_brend001"></a><span>Loreal Paris</span></div>
```

to

```
<div><a id="filt_brend001"><span>Loreal Paris</span></a></div>
```

Fiddle with above in action is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2N7jk/1/).

Comment: @nabiullinas Which jQuery are you using? `.bind()` is deprecated. Use `.on()`

Comment: I also tried id. It worked befor, but I needed to integrate http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html plugin. It makes some modifications with div. After it it crashed